# Linq Query with three tables join to send alert after x days

Tags: c#, linq, entities

I want to implement email functionality where user can send email to profiles who have not logged in since 20 days also i want repeat after every 10 days.

```
    I have three tables 
    1) "details" table where profile is maintained.
    2) "notify" table where i keep a track of notification send to profiles.
    3) "profile" table where i keep track of the login information of profile.
```

so far i have tried this-

```
    list = (from c in ctx.details.AsEnumerable()
                       join u in ctx.profile.AsEnumerable()
                       join a in ctx.notify..AsEnumerable()
                       on c.profileid equals u.profileid equals a.profileid
                       where (u.last_login_date == null && 
                      (DateTime.Now - u.last_login_date).TotalDays >= 20)
                       select new details
                       {
                           profileid = c.profileid.ToString(),
                           firstname = c.firstname,
                           lastname = c.lastname,
                           email = c.email

                       }).ToList();
```

- ```
  My tables are ->
    details             notify                profile
    -----------        ------------          -------------- 
    profileid          profileid              profileid
    firstname          alert_date(datetime)   last_login_date(datetime)
    lastname
    email
  ```

where the alert_date is the date if he has been send email earlier and last_login_date is
the date when he has lastly login in the profile.

But I am sure this is not going to work.I want the details table to be filled with details.
Help me out.

Comment: you don't have a solution @stian.net?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that *should* return you the details object for every profile that hasn't had a login in 20 days or every 10 day increment after that (e.g. 30 days, 40 days).

```
list = (from c in ctx.detail
       join u in ctx.profile
       on c.profileid equals u.profileid
       join a in ctx.notify
       on c.profileid equals a.profileid
       let datediff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(u.last_login_date).TotalDays
       where datediff >= 20 && datediff % 10 == 0
       select c).ToList();
```

I have removed the `AsEnumerable` calls since it is always good to let the database do as much of the work as it can.  It is off the top of my head and untested so there still could be some errors, but that should be a good starting point.

Comment: If you need any other information, don't forget that you can create an anonymous type by changing `select c` at the end to `select new { Property1 = <somevalue>, Property2 = <othervalue> }`.

Comment: @SPFiredrake is absolutely correct. I had removed the original anonymous type because it was all data from the `detail` entity, but it can be easily added back.